# TLS 1.2 on the Fleetboard

Tags: android, tls1.2, fleetboard

When testing the App it was noticed that it works, but no data readings are passed to the backend.
The error message is an SSLHandshakeException with reference to a version mismatch.
The MQTT Broker in the backend enforced TLS 1.2, in the debugging of app page I noticed, that the MQTT Client only uses TLS 1.0 as "enabled Protocols".

A short research shows that the availability of TLS 1.2 for Android <= 4.4 seems to be a common problem:
https://ankushg.com/posts/tls-1.2-on-android/

The following points must be checked for the solution:

- Is TLS 1.2 installed as a protocol on the fleet boards?
- Is the protocol enabled?
- Is the MQTT client compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.2 should work when using customized clients for http or mqtt.